# using for loop to copy selected files in directory and subdirectories to new directory with the same structure

Tags: for-loop, cmd, xcopy

```
for /r "C:\Users\bui\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test1" %i in (*03.json)  do copy "%i" "C:\Users\bui\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test2"
```

i want to copy all 03.json files from test1 to test2 but in test1 folder, there are subfolders, and in those subfolders also have 03.json files. With for loop i cant loop through subfolders and copy 03.json files in it, but i also want to copy those subfolders from test1 to test2 with those 03.jon files in it. is there possible way to do it?

i tried using xcopy to copy those subfolders first then use for loop but no use, bc they copy all files to "C:\Users\bui\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test2"

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `robocopy /?` and read the output help. There can be used `robocopy "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test1" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test2" *03.json /S /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:1 /W:1 >nul` to copy all `*03.json` files in entire directory tree of `test1` to `test2` with replicating the directory tree.

Comment: @Mofi thank you for your answer, the command work perfectly, but my boss keep telling me that add if command to the for loop could make it work aswell. You got any ideal how to do it?

Comment: Ask your boss to sbow you then! If they aren't just pulling your leg, and they do show you, you can post their response, and we'll see how clever they really are. Just be aware that the example already commented is unlikely to be improved upon for simplicity, command length, or efficiency.

Comment: In a command prompt window can be used also `for /R "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test1" %I in (*03.json) do @for /F "tokens=6* delims=\" %J in ("%~dpI") do @md "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test2\%K" 2>nul & copy /B /Y "%I" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test2\%K" >nul` which is less efficient than the usage of __ROBOCOPY__ designed for exactly such file copying tasks. BTW: The folder name `Annotation Traing Package` should be most likely `Annotation Training Package`.

Answer (score 0):

`RoBoCopy` is the best method to do this IMHO.

```
Robocopy "C:\Users\bui\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test1" "C:\Users\bui\Desktop\Annotation Traing Package\test2" *03.json /E /S /B
```

The `Robocopy` utility is made to copy directory trees and matching files and has been included in windows since Windows 7 released in 2009.

Note I used `/E` assuming you would want the folders which are empty assuming you may have things like log folders which contain no "03.json" files

If you do not want to create empty directories when they do not contain "03.json" files, then simply omit the `/E` option